# Opening large PDF and checking signature in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

We are working with PDF files and want to check them if they are signed or not.
Currently we are using SecureBlackbox and it is working fine for small files.

Problem is with large (more than 2GB) files. When loading it gets out of memory or similar error.

Is there any way or library (for .net) to open large files and getting signature info from PDF?

What I tried so far with no success: ITextSharp, PdfSharp, SecureBlackbox

Ideal way would be not loading whole content of file, just information what is needed, so not to use so much memory or space.

Thank you for your suggestions.
Have a nice day.
Fitik

Comment: Did you already tried to divide your pdf in some parts, check each part and then see the signature? Please, post the relevant code to we help you.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114464/c-sharp-verifying-pdf-signature

Comment: "Ideal way would be not loading whole content of file, just information what is needed, so not to use so much memory or space." Since part of checking cryptographic signatures of a PDF is to make sure no changes/modifications have been done to the PDF since it was signed I think you would always have to have all the bytes of the PDF file. Where is the 2GB file located? Client machine? Your server?

Comment: Have you tried compiling 64 bit and using SecureBlackBox 64 bit?  2^31 (2GB) is usually the maximum memory that can be allocated to a 32 bit process.

Comment: You also mention having tried *ITextSharp, PdfSharp*. In case of the former, have you made sure to open the PDF in partial reading mode?

Comment: @Que44 Afaik you can split it to smaller parts only after loading it all, so its the same problem.

Comment: @Zserbinator No, that does not help at all. It doesnt solve big file problem.

Comment: @Ryan Hmm, you may be right about validating the signature, but I dont even need to validate it, just to see if it is signed by any. Its being done on our server.

Comment: "Thank you for your suggestions." Are you looking for suggestions for just "ITextSharp, PdfSharp, SecureBlackbox"? Or are you looking for any suggestions? If the latter, are you looking for just free suggestions? Also why is "not to use so much memory or space." important for you?

Comment: @AlanK Do they have extra 64bit version of their libraries? Didnt find on web. I also tried compile project as x64 but also failed. Will yet try latest version of SecureBlackbox.

Comment: @Ryan I am also looking for other alternative 3rd party libraries, if you know of any? Prefer free, but if not available, we can also try paid ones, depends on price. Well the less memory used the better :-)

Comment: Is the PDF on the same server instance as you are doing the processing on? If so, do you have a file path access to it from your code? Or do you first have to download/access the PDF file from a different file server?

Comment: @mkl yes i tried partial mode constructor like:  reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(ws), null, true); but i think it is only relevant for reading from file, not from stream (which is my case).

Comment: @Ryan it is streamed from client, so I dont have access to file on disc - thats the main problem.

Comment: *"but i think it is only relevant for reading from file, not from stream (which is my case)"* - to process pdf files they need to be provided with random access, i.e. as a file or byte array. For a 2 GB pdf stream, therefore, you'll need 2 GB in memory or on disk for the unparsed data. For the parsed data you'll need extra memory, and that's where you'll need much less in partial mode.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if your file server hosting the PDF file supports byte range requests, and the Stream you have supports random access, then theoretically you could just download the exact bytes needed to read the parts that you want. I am unaware of any out of the box solution that will do this for you though.

Comment: The C++ Windows DLLs are available in 32 and 64 bit versions [link](https://www.nsoftware.com/platforms/cpp/) but I can't claim experience with very, very large files such as yours.  The .NET version is built for AnyCPU (implicitly 32 bit, old FAQ: [link](https://www.nsoftware.com/kb/xml/10230702.rst)), so you'll probably have to play with the former and `[DllImport]`.

Comment: @Ryan *"Strictly speaking, if your file server hosting the PDF file supports byte range requests,"* - that would be a (theoretical) option if the file was on the server and the client wanted to check. If i understand the op correctly, though, it is the other way around here, the client streams the file to the server and the server wants to check.

Comment: @Fitik *"it is streamed from client, so I dont have access to file on disc - thats the main problem."* - Is it no option to store the pdf streamed from the client in a temporary file on the server for as long as it is being processed?

Comment: @mkl "to process pdf files they need to be provided with random access, i.e. as a file or byte array"  Thats the question. Technically, if you need only some particular information it could be possible to get sldo from the nonseekable stream (depends on information). That was original question, anyway. But maybe you are right and only solution is to write stream to temp file and process it.

Comment: @AlanK Yes, there is only one version for .NET. I found out, we were using few years old version. In the current one, they fixed the problem with processing stream internally in file stream instead of memorystream, which is working, but still technically involves saving everything into file. But that maybe my only option.

Comment: @Fitik The problem is that you parse PDFs from the back as there is the pointer to the latest PDF object cross reference table or stream segment. You then have to follow that pointer to some place and read the cross references there. From there you follow a link to the previous segment etc. Having collected all those segments you use the information to locate the specific PDF objects that contain the information you are looking for.

Comment: If you go through the stream only once from front to back, you have to parse every object you pass because every object might be related to the information you seek. Thus, you eventually have read through your stream only once but have amassed more memory usage for temporary parsing results. Of course you can try and _guess_ that some object you came along is the one containing the information you look for, but such guesses can go totally wrong...

Comment: "it is streamed from client, so I dont have access to file on disc" I missed this comment earlier. Why not check the info you want client side then? Do you have a client side application? Or perhaps they accessing your server through a webpage? Then there is no need to transfer any PDF file data.